# Best practices for redirect to login page if session expired

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I want to redirect the user to login page, if session expired. I found many ways to do this but what is the best (or default) way in ASP.Net MVC5 with OWIN?
Probably it works out of the box? But How?

Razor:

- set a session variable after valid login
- add this in _Layout.cshtml:

```cs
@if (Session["IsLogin"] == null)
{
    Session.Abandon();
    Response.Redirect("~/LoginControllerName/LoginActionName");
}
```

Global.asax:

- It is possible to use these two methods but I don't know how.

```cs
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when a new session is started
}

protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when a session is expired
}
```

My current solution:

- all controller inherit from `BaseController`
- I used the OnAuthorizationAttribute because redirected should only be executed if it is a non-public page.

```cs
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (this.Session["RedirectAfterLogin"] == null)
        {
            var isAnonymousAllowed = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true) || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true);
            if (!isAnonymousAllowed)
            {
                this.Session["RedirectAfterLogin"] = this.Request.Url?.ToString();
                filterContext.Result = this.RedirectToAction("LoginActionName", "LoginControllerName");
            }
        }
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

- After Redirect sign out the user:

```cs
if (this.AuthenticationManager == null)
{
    this.SetAuthenticationManager(this.HttpContext?.GetOwinContext()?.Authentication);
}

this.AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

- After valid login set session variable:

```cs
this.Session["RedirectAfterLogin"] = this.Request.Url?.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A redirect after expired session with additional information like the current page can handled with a custom `CookieAuthenticationProvider`.

```cs
public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        var url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
        var provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider();
        var originalHandler = provider.OnApplyRedirect;
        provider.OnApplyRedirect = context =>
        {
            var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
            var uri = new Uri(context.RedirectUri);
            var returnUrl = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query)[context.Options.ReturnUrlParameter];
            routeValues.Add(context.Options.ReturnUrlParameter, returnUrl);
            context.RedirectUri = url.Action("Login", "Account", routeValues);
            originalHandler.Invoke(context);
        };
        provider.OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager));


        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = provider,
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use default startup of owin in mvc5

```
 public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {

                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thats looks like my configuration. I have additionally set ```SlidingExpiration = true``` and 
```ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)```. But in my web.config I have a different session timeout ```<sessionState mode="InProc"  timeout="20">```